# RN Apollo Client 3.0 - handle refetch with merge function

Tags: react-apollo, apollo-client

I am recently migrating to apollo client 3.0 from 2.0.

I have a query that requires fetch more and pagination.

By doing,

```
const cache = new InMemoryCache({
  typePolicies: {
    Query: {
      fields: {
        getData: {
          // Handles incoming data
          keyArgs: [],
          merge(existing ={/*some default object fields*/}, incoming) {
            return {
              ...existing,
              pageInfo: incoming.pageInfo,
              edges: [...existing.edges, ...incoming.edges],
            };
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

I was able to handle both initial query/fetch and pagination.
However, I am having trouble with how to handle refetch.
With this merge function, refetched data get just concatenated with existing cache data.
I am not able to find how to correctly handle this in merge function.

If anyone know how to handle this, please let me know.

Comment: I have the same issue. Looks like a bug to me. Why do I have to worry about merging in this case? Shouldn't refetchQueries() erase old cache values?

Comment: Yeah I think this is a bug or drawback of this new structure. But 3.0 was released last month so I believe there will be more things coming. As far as I know, Apollo is really good at managing documentations, blogs(apollo blogs), and features.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to work around by observing args.

```
const cache = new InMemoryCache({
      typePolicies: {
        Query: {
          fields: {
            getData: {
              // Handles incoming data
              keyArgs: [],
              merge(existing ={/*some default object fields*/}, incoming, {args}) {
                if(args && !args.after){
                    // Initial fetch or refetch
                    return incoming;
                }
                
                // Pagination
                return {
                  ...existing,
                  pageInfo: incoming.pageInfo,
                  edges: [...existing.edges, ...incoming.edges],
                };
              },
            },
          },
        },
      },
    });
```

Comment: I'm facing same issue. This seems to work, but what is `args.after`? A link to the document would be very helpful!

Comment: Well, there is no document. I don't know what kind of API's you are working with. But my team works with GraphQl. In GraphQl pagination, based on facebook's spec, there is something called pageInfo object given by end point to client. In there, usually there is hasNextPage and endCursor. args stands for arguments and args.after is endCursor passed to API with the query. To give a simple example, you have a list view that shows 10 items initially. As user reached the end of the list, you want to fetch more. At the time, you pass endCursor provided before, and this is after here.

Comment: To give a more specific example, let's say we have "query getSomeItems(first:Int, after: Int)". If you are not familiar with GraphQl, understand this query as API that client uses to fetch items. In this query, first and after are arguments provided along with query. first means how many items you want to fetch. To explain after, imagine a database that has a list of items. Each item has id. Initially, you want to start with the most recent item so that you don't provide after. But if you want to continue fetch more after first fetch, you have to provide after, which is the id of the last item

Comment: So to conclude what is the after doing in the code above, we can use it to check if the items we received is from initial fetch or some Nth fetch. As I explained above, initial fetch does not have after, but fetch more or any subsequent fetches must have after. The trouble we have with Apollo 3.0 (or at least i had at the time) is that I had difficult time to distinguish among fetchMore, refetch, and initial fetch.

Comment: For somehow who is not familiar with pagination using endCursor, check: https://www.apollographql.com/blog/explaining-graphql-connections-c48b7c3d6976/ and https://uxdesign.cc/why-facebook-says-cursor-pagination-is-the-greatest-d6b98d86b6c0

Comment: @JunmingWang the args are your query variables. In this example after false means it's an initial fetch or refetch, but it could be another args for example start === 0 or a nextToken, it all depends on your specific query for the pagination.